# Displaying categories?

Tags: php, wordpress

Such a problem in WordPress, I want to display on the page information about categories, as well as their image ... I added the image in the category using the ACF plugin, all data is displayed: name, description, but the picture is not, here is my code, what's wrong tell me?

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories(array('hide_empty' => 0, 'taxonomy' => 'authors-category'));
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    $id = $cat->cat_ID;
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $cat_img = get_field('category_image', $cat);
?>
<!--Author-->
<div class="author-block">
    <div class="photo-author" style="background: url(<?php echo $cat_img['url']; ?>) #f3b458 no-repeat center center;background-size: cover;"></div>
    <div class="name-author"><?php echo $cat->name ?></div>
    <div class="count-post-author">
        41 post </br>
        <a href="#">See All Posts By The Author</a>
    </div>
    <div class="content-author">
        <?php echo $cat->description ?>
    </div>
</div>
<!--End Block-->
<?php } ?>
```

This is what happened, only in place of the figure should be pictures:

[image]

Comment: is it just displaying a no image icon? it may be your path. do a var_dump($cat_img); to see what that outputs

Comment: @comphonia , it gets the number "39", where it comes from, I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by switching the settings in the plugin
Array to URL
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ko8Y.png)